# Update multiple SQL records using one PHP/MySQLi query

Tags: php, mysqli

Is it possible to update multiple records in one MySQLi query?
There are 4 records to be updated (1 for each element level) when the submit button is clicked.
The results are posted to a separate PHP page which runs the query and returns the user back to the edit page. `elementid` is 1,2,3,4 and corresponds with Earth, wind, fire, water. These never change (hence readonly or hidden)

```
<form id="edituser" name="edituser" method="post" action="applylevelchanges.php">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Edit Element Level</legend>
        <?php
            while($userdetails->fetch())
            {?>
                <input name="clientid" id="clientid" type="text" size="8" value="<?php echo $clientid; ?>" hidden />
                <input name="elementid" id="elementid" type="text" size="8" value="<?php echo $elementid;?>" hidden />
                <input name="elemname" id="elemname" type="text" size="15" value="<?php echo $elemname; ?>" readonly />
                <input name="elemlevel" id="elemlevel" type="text" size="8" required value="<?php echo $elemlevel; ?>" /></br>
                </br>
        <?php }?>


    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit">Edit Student Levels</button>

</form>
```

And the code to apply the changes

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['clientid']) && isset($_POST['elementid']) && isset($_POST['elemname']) && isset($_POST['elemlevel'])) {
    $db = createConnection();
    $clientid = $_POST['clientid'];
    $elementid = $_POST['elementid'];
    $elemname = $_POST['elemname'];
    $elemlevel = $_POST['elemlevel'];

    $updatesql = "update stuelement set elemlevel=? where clientid=? and elementid=?";
    $doupdate = $db->prepare($updatesql);
    $doupdate->bind_param("iii", $elemlevel, $clientid, $elementid);
    $doupdate->execute();
    $doupdate->close();
    $db->close();
    header("location: edituserlevel.php");
    exit;
} else {
    echo "<p>Some parameters are missing, cannot update database</p>";
}
```

Comment: "and elementid IN(?)" where you have concatenated the element ids? I.e. '1,2,3,4' or whatever they are?

Comment: Sorry, element id is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. Sorry that's not clear from original query